# datatable pagination not working

Tags: datatable

I have used datatable for pagination ,all is working fine except that next prev pagination is not showing first time ,after `onkeypress` event in search-box it is working fine, in console it  is showing following error:

```
"TypeError: aoLocal[(i + iRowspan)][j] is undefined".
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the table structure. Unended tags cause the undefined rowspan. For example, this structure breaks the table rendering with DataTables:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>I am a visible header</th>
            <th>Hey! what the hell... Why am i invisible?</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Breaks due to the 2nd `<tr>` which should be `</tr>`.